# Get top row for muliple registers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I came across a piece of code that generates SELECT queries from a template.

The template:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM   MRH_0000004 WITH (nolock) 
WHERE  MachineRegisterId = ${id}
ORDER  BY UtcTime
```

When the code has to retrieve multiple records, it generates one large query that gets the union of all individual queries based on the template above.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM   mrh_0000004 WITH (nolock) 
        WHERE  machineregisterid = 55 
        ORDER  BY utctime) q 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM   mrh_0000004 WITH (nolock) 
        WHERE  machineregisterid = 56 
        ORDER  BY utctime) q 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT TOP 1 * 
        FROM   mrh_0000004 WITH (nolock) 
        WHERE  machineregisterid = 57 
        ORDER  BY utctime) q
```

This is a query that gets the TOP 1 result from each group, without using a GROUP BY clause. These chains can get quite long, resulting in large queries from the client to the server.

Can this query be refactored using GROUP BY?

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mrh_0000004] 
  ( 
     [machineregisterid] [INT] NOT NULL, 
     [utctime]           [DATETIME] NOT NULL, 
     [value]             [FLOAT] NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT [pk_MRH_0000004] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [machineregisterid] ASC 
     , [utctime] ASC ) 
  )
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, **try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: See also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

Answer (score 2):

#### `WITH (nolock)`

While there is nothing inherently wrong with using `WITH (nolock)` per-se, it's mostly meant to be used within transactions that have an [isolation level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) that *does* cause locks, to mark that specific table as an exception to the locking. If your whole transaction is meant to not have any locks, just declare this at the top:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

#### Use variables

This will potentially help you make the code more readable and flexible.

```
--Using a variable for readability and flexibility
--This would make it easier also to turn into a script 
--like a stored procedure in the future
DECLARE @top INT;
SET @top = 1;
```

Then you can do things like `SELECT TOP (@top) * FROM ...` and that will allow to easily adapt it if you want top 3, top 5, 10 etc. instead of just the top-most row.

---

## Approach

As thoroughly explained and illustrated in [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group) on DBA.StackExchange site, there are two common ways of doing this which are simpler and much more efficient than `UNION ALL`.

#### Using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Per MSDN:

> Returns the sequential number of a row within a partition of a result set, starting at 1 for the first row in each partition.

As applied to your query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
DECLARE @top INT;
SET @top = 1;

WITH grouped AS (
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        --This is equivalent to GROUP BY + ORDER BY combined
        --where the first item in each group/partition will have
        --row number 1 and so on, based on the ORDER BY clause
        (PARTITION BY machineregisterid 
        ORDER BY utctime) AS row_num
      , *
    FROM mrh_0000004
)
SELECT * FROM grouped
--Using <= in case @top was greater than 1
WHERE row_num <= @top;
```

#### Using [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

According to TechNet:

> The APPLY operator allows you to invoke a table-valued function for each row returned by an outer table expression of a query.

Again, as applied to your query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
DECLARE @top INT;
SET @top = 1;

SELECT 
    mrh1.machineregisterid,
    mrh2.utctime,
    mrh2.[value] --using brackets because VALUE is an ODBC reserved keyword
FROM mrh_0000004 AS mrh1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (@top) * 
    FROM mrh_0000004
    WHERE machineregisterid = mrh1.machineregisterid
    ORDER BY utctime
) AS mrh2
ORDER BY machineregisterid, utctime;
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work using ROW_NUMBER(). I want to see how it compares to using APPLY, but I can't figure out why the APPLY query returns `@top` number of records from `mrh2` for every record in `mrh1`.

Comment: I may have got my syntax incorrect, I don't use APPLY very often (more typically use ROW_NUMBER()), I'll check it again soon and try to fix it